# Реализовать всплывающее окно с условием Bitrix

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, битрикс

Как реализовать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку (в корзину) или (отложить) тот товар который распродан, всплывало окно ( к сожалению товар распродан)? Может есть готовые модули или примеру?

Answer (score 1):

На ум пришло такое решение, но оно требует кастомизации шаблона:
1. Если товар отсутствует то записывать "0" в параметр data-buy кнопки события ( в корзину и отложить)
2.При клике на одну из кнопок через javascript проверять значение data-buy, если оно 0 - тогда блокировать все события и выводить ваш попап.